# AvAudiorecorder not functioning properly in iOS 5.1.1 and iPhone4

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, avaudiorecorder

I am working on an audio recording feature in my app. I am using this code:

```
-(void)startAudioRecorder:(NSError**)error{
    
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    NSError *err = nil;
    [audioSession setCategory :AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&err];
    if(err){
        NSLog(@"audioSession: %@ %d %@", [err domain], [err code], [[err userInfo] description]);
        return;
    }
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:&err];
    
        NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] ;
        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];//kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,kAudioFormatAAC
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 1] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];
    
    NSString *absolutePath=[self getAbsoluteAudioFilePath];
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:absolutePath]){
       // [[NSFileManager defaultManager ] removeItemAtPath:absolutePath error:nil];
    }
    NSError *audioRecorderError=nil;
    NSURL *absoluteUrl=[NSURL fileURLWithPath:absolutePath];
    
    self.audioRecorder=[[[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:absoluteUrl settings:recordSetting error:&audioRecorderError] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"%s audioRecorder created=%@",__func__,self.audioRecorder);
    
    [self.audioRecorder setDelegate: self];
    BOOL prepared=[self.audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    BOOL record=[self.audioRecorder record];
    
    if(!prepared || !record){
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"message" message:@"something wrong" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }
    *error=audioRecorderError;
    //[recordSetting release];
    //recordSetting=nil;
    
    
}
```

From various blogs I found above code for recording and it's working as expected in all iOS devices, I have tested on the iPad, iPod, and iPhone. Unfortunately the above code recording with very less voice  in **iPhone 4, iOS 5.1.1** device rest all combinations are good, I have opened and recorded my voice in voice memos, SpeakEasy apps for the same hardware device those two apps working well which means hardware is working well.

Is there any modification that will solve my issue? What would be the best way to record the voice with high quality?

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted solution on behalf of the question author to move it to the answer section)*.

Added below lines in my method which solves problem

```
 NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    //Set the general audio session category
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &setCategoryErr];
    
    //Make the default sound route for the session be to use the speaker
    UInt32 doChangeDefaultRoute = 1;
    AudioSessionSetProperty (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker, sizeof (doChangeDefaultRoute), &doChangeDefaultRoute);
    
    //Activate the customized audio session
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: &activationErr];
```